# How to properly handle events on labels ontop of a button?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class which I inherit from Button. In this class, I create labels which I can use as custom button captions. The problem I have on these custom buttons is when I click the label nothing happens, and if I click outside the label but still on the button it works as usual. To solve this I wrote:

```
lblTitle.Click += new EventHandler(LabelClick);
```

And in LabelClick I wrote:

```
private void LabelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClick(e);
}
```

This worked good, but then I noticed that I didnt get the clickanimation of the click, when I clicked on the label. So I made the same thing with onMouseDown and Up.

```
        lblTitle.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(LabelMouseDown);
        lblTitle.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(LabelMouseUp);

        private void LabelMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
        }

        private void LabelMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseUp(e);
        }
```

But then I sometimes get the effect of clicking two times on the button. So now I'm wondering, how do I give the user the same click animation when clicked on the button and the label ontop of the button - without making the button click twice?

Thanks in advance and if you gonna downgrade this question, please leave a comment on why!

Comment: Detect the click on button not on labels. Then you can check if mouse down/up is on label or not (by code). WinForms isn't WPF, it doesn't make these stuff pretty easy...

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Can you give an example? I didnt quite get what you meant. When I dont detect clicks on the labels, that part of the button gets unclickable for me :(

Comment: I'd really like to know why you place labels over buttons. What do you achieve in addition to using the button's caption?

Comment: Make that:  `lblTitle.Click += buttonTitle_Click;` instead of `lblTitle.Click += new EventHandler(LabelClick);` and delete all the rest! Also make sure the Labels are enabled!

Comment: Don't use a Label, it interferes too much with the button's events.  Just use the button's Paint event and paint the text onto the button with TextRenderer.DrawText().

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I have more than one label (with different alignments) on the button, and buttons only have one captions :(

Comment: @HansPassant Really interesting! I've never worked with the Paint event before, but I'll definitely look into it. Edit: Do you have a link on this perhaps?

Comment: @HansPassant That's what I was going to suggest next... :-)

Comment: Im sorry, I dont know how to work with this paint event. Can someone make an answer with a sample code pls?

Comment: Try not to be helpless.  Google "how to use textrenderer.drawtext in a paint event handler".

Comment: Try not to be a douchbag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that LabelClick & LabelMouseDown & LabelMouseUp all these three events are fired when you click the label which fires them in the base button. so your click event is duplicated when you make a MouseDown event. (this should be a comment, but i dont have enough reputation to leave a comment, hope it will help :) )

Comment: Then let's give you some!